# How to restart sshd after assembly?

Tags: linux, openssh, sshd, oracle-linux

it is necessary to update the openssh server to the latest version, since everything is closed, it has come to manually assemble it

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --with-pam --with-selinux --with-privsep-path=/var/lib/sshd/ --with-kerberos5=/etc/krb5.conf --sysconfdir=/etc/ssh --with-default-path=/usr/bin --with-pid-dir=/run && make
```

the version was updated, the installation was successful, but I can't restart it
I get an error

```
Bad configuration option: GSSAPIKexAlgorithms
```

this data is contained in the file `/etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config`

```
GSSAPIKexAlgorithms gss-curve25519-sha256-,gss-nistp256-sha256-,gss-group14-sha256-,gss-group16-sha512-,gss-gex-sha1-,gss-group14-sha1-
```

I tried to comment, but it didn't help, how to fix it?
version OpenSSH_9.3p1

Comment: If you commented it out and still got the same error you may have the same property in a different config file. sshd also looks in `~/.ssh` for config files by default.

Comment: @CliffArmstrong I don’t know of any distribution that allows for `~/.ssh/sshd_config` to be used. How would a user’s config file manage to modify a system daemon that is already running? - Documentation checked on both the OpenSSH and RedHat sites.

Comment: I've done this on both arch and ubuntu server. Used with `match` to limit a specific user's connection options. I'm not sure it _does_ modify a running sshd but it wouldn't be hard for the daemon to parse the config file once a user is selected (as it does with other files in that same folder). A more well know example of this would be `.htaccess` files in apache2. Regardless, the issue was something else... so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"GSSAPIKexAlgorithms" isn't a standard Openssh server feature. It's apparently part of a feature added to Openssh by some Linux vendors. For example, [here is the patch page](https://sources.debian.org/patches/openssh/1:9.2p1-2/) for Debian's version of Openssh 9.2. ["gssapi.patch"](https://sources.debian.org/patches/openssh/1:9.2p1-2/gssapi.patch/) on that page adds support for GSSAPIKexAlgorithms and some other configuration options. I'm not familiar enough with Oracle Linux to find information on their Openssh patches.

[This page](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config) is the Openssh team's version of the sshd configuration options, and you'll notice that it doesn't describe "GSSAPIKexAlgorithms" or certain other GSS options.

If you're not using GSSAPI, you could edit /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config to "comment out" the options which sshd doesn't like. To comment out a line, place a "#" (pound sign) at the beginning of the line. After editing the file, run "sshd -t" to test whether the configuration files have any problems. Then restart the `sshd` process to enable the changes.

If you are using GSSAPI and need those options to work, then you should look to your Linux vendor for an updated version of Openssh server, or else the source code changes that they're making to add support for the GSSAPI features. If necessary, you could try downloading the Debian patch that was referenced above, and try to apply it to the Openssh source code that you downloaded.